# How to use subclust in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I have a question: how to use subclust() function in matlab with an image loaded with imread() function? I have a code

```
rgb = imread('6_rubets.jpg');
gr = rgb2gray(rgb);
[c, s] = subclust(gr, 0.3);
```

I need to get the cluster centers on this image, and in the result I need to classify pixels on the image.
But I have the error:

```
Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in subclust (line 169)
    dx = (thePoint - X) .* new_accumMultp;

Error in lab_1 (line 3)
[c, s] = subclust(gr, 0.3);
```

What do I need to do to find a claster centers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you upload the image? Also, you mean to say that the entire [help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/subclust.html) is unhelpful?

Comment: @Dev-iL I can upload the image, but it is the random image from Internet.
Full my code
`rgb = imread('test.jpg');
gr = rgb2gray(rgb);
[c, s] = subclust(gr, 0.3);
imshow(gr);`

but I have the error

`Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in subclust (line 169)
 dx = (thePoint - X) .* new_accumMultp;

Error in lab_1 (line 3)
[c, s] = subclust(gr, 0.3);`

Comment: And I have never used matlab before... Sorry if my question looks stupid.

Comment: Firstly, please edit the question to include the code instead of putting it in the comment. Next, explain what you're trying to do before mentioning the function.. Maybe there's another solution that doesn't require it.

Comment: @Dev-iL, thank you for advice - I have edited the question and added some informations.

Comment: I can't test it but what if you cast gr to type single like so :gr = single(rgb2gray(rgb)); It looks like subclust does not like data of the type uint8, as your image probably is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because `subclust` doesn't support inputs that are `uint8` (or any integer I suppose...).  I suspect that internally, `subclust` is creating arrays / matrices of type `double`, then when it is trying to do operations with those arrays / matrices with your image, you're getting that error.  The operations done with mixing the different variable types is not allowed, as hinted by the error.

As such, try casting your image to `double`, then run the code again.  This won't change the actual numbers, but it will change the class of variable instead (`double`).  I did this and it worked for me.  As an example, I used `cameraman.tif` that's part of MATLAB's system path:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif'); %// Image already grayscale
[c,s] = subclust(double(im), 0.3);
```

---

In your case, you would have to do:

```
rgb = imread('6_rubets.jpg');
gr = rgb2gray(rgb);
[c, s] = subclust(double(gr), 0.3);
```